# iOS Error when sending email or sms

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sendmessage

I'm trying to send sms and email from an iOS app, but I encounter some problems.

I took the code from a tutorial, for example the sms code :

```
func sendMessage() {
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var message = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    // Contacts
    var phoneNumbers = [String]()
    var phoneNumberNb: Int = prefs.objectForKey("phonenumberssaved")!.count
    for(var i = 0; i < phoneNumberNb; i++) {
        phoneNumbers.append(prefs.objectForKey("phonenumberssaved")!.objectAtIndex(i) as! String)
    }

    println(phoneNumbers)

    message.recipients = phoneNumbers
    message.body = self.messageText
    message.messageComposeDelegate = self

    self.presentViewController(message, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

and I printed my datas (they seems to be ok), but when I try to send it, the app crash with a

> 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' and it show me a strange file with a line highlighted : '0x4b5164 <+64>:  trap'...

Comment: What is the output for.  println(phoneNumbers) this sentance

Comment: the output is :   [01 47 89 65 83]

Comment: So, the number is in right format.? I think the number should be like "+1999999999" or "999999999" etc..

Comment: Thanks, I am going to change it but there is the same error with emails, so I think that's not the only mistake ?

Comment: What is the self.messageText? it is textbox or string variable.?

[@"12345678", @"72345524"] your number array must be like this.

Comment: try hardcoding a phone number to message. recipients and check if its working.
other wise mostly it would be the issue of phone number format

Comment: self.messageText is a string var, why does my array have to be like that ? @ is for obj-c and I'm coding in swift ?

Comment: i am just telling you that it should be like this. I know its obj-c. I dont have any knowledge in swift that why giving a obj-c example.

Comment: @ V.J : Ok scuse me I didn't understood it

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional unwrapping. Also, you don't need to process each array element:

```
func sendMessage() {
    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let message = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    // Contacts
    if let phoneNumbers = prefs.objectForKey("phonenumberssaved") as? [String] {
        println(phoneNumbers)

        message.recipients = phoneNumbers
        message.body = "some body"
        message.messageComposeDelegate = self

        self.presentViewController(message, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your code but not working, same error :S

Answer (score 0):

You can try this before init your "message", some device don't have option to send message:

```
if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
    ...
}
```

Verify if **phoneNumbers** is not nil before setting **message.recipients**, this can be append if there is no phone number saved in user preferences.

And **self.messageText** is not nil too by the way.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I just tested it, and it's crossing right in the statement, but always that error...

Comment: I'm testing the app on an iPod Touch, but it can send message with iMessage with the same api than sms, and it's passing the statement so I guess this isn't the problem